# Request and get response from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to send customer info to server and get response from it. My flow is to send customer info using POST from JSP to Servlet. From Servlet, I will send data and get status from response. But when I send data to server, I got http error 500. I can send data to HTTP or HTTPS. If I have to use HTTPS protocol to request server, how can I achieve this?

Here's the servlet code.

```
    String refNo = request.getParameter("ref");
    String amount = request.getParameter("amt");

    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);

    URL      url;
    URLConnection    urlConn;
    DataOutputStream cgiInput;

    // URL of target page script.
    url = new URL("http://uat.telemoney.com.sg/easypay2/paymentpage.do");
    urlConn = url.openConnection();

    urlConn.setDoInput(true);
    urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");



    String content = "mid=" + URLEncoder.encode(MERCHANT_ID) + "&ref=" + URLEncoder.encode(refNo)+ "&cur=" + URLEncoder.encode("SGD");
    content += "&statusurl=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.winsondbs.com:8080/TestWeb/Servlet/DBSController") + "&paytype=" + URLEncoder.encode("2");
    content += "&ccnum=" + URLEncoder.encode("5111111111111115") + "&ccdate=" + URLEncoder.encode("1511") + "&cccvv=" + URLEncoder.encode("989");
    content += "&amt=" + URLEncoder.encode(amount) + "&creditCardName=" + URLEncoder.encode("raymond") + "&cccvv=" + URLEncoder.encode("989");

    System.out.println(content);
    // Send POST output.
    cgiInput = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
    cgiInput.writeBytes(content);
    cgiInput.flush();
    cgiInput.close();

    // reads the CGI response and print it inside the servlet content
    BufferedReader cgiOutput = 
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter servletOutput = response.getWriter();        
    servletOutput.print("<html><body><h1>This is the Source Servlet</h1><p />");
    String line = null;
    while (null != (line = cgiOutput.readLine())){
        servletOutput.println(line);
    }
    cgiOutput.close();
    servletOutput.print("</body></html>");
    servletOutput.close();
```

Below is the error:

```
    Jan 16, 2013 8:33:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet DBSController threw exception
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://uat.telemoney.com.sg/easypay2/paymentpage.do
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at servlet.com.dbs.www.DBSController.doPost(DBSController.java:163)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that the url you trying to connect is working?

Comment: how can i check that connect url is working or not? I'm new to java servlet.. when i just use <form> tag to redirect or just use request.sendRedirect(), it's ok.. but i don't get status..

Comment: as i can suggest, it doesn't work properly since it gives internal server error --> Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://uat.telemoney.com.sg/easypay2/paymentpage.do

Comment: Figure out what's bad about your request--we cannot look on their server to see what about your request is causing the error on their side. @MustafaGenç That doesn't prove very much; sending no parameters to something that clearly expects them is likely to cause failure.

Comment: so can you show me sample code of request server with https ?? any help is ok for me.. i need it urgently... another is can i catch response string using web debugger like fiddler2, even server response with post ??

Comment: DBSController.java:163 What line is this in your controller? That will help narrow down where it is failing

Comment: You need to read `urlConn.getErrorStream()` to see the error page which may contain more detail about the problem. If you can't figure out what the error page is telling you, edit your question to include it.

Comment: @Sean: the error is coming from the other host, not from the servlet itself. Line 163 is obviously the line wherein the actual HTTP request to the other host is fired by `urlConn.getInputStream()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not write DataOutputStream. Is the server on the other end expecting DataOutputStream.

Replace this

```
cgiInput = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
cgiInput.writeBytes(content);
```

with

```
cgiInput = urlConn.getOutputStream());
cgiInput.write(content.getBytes());
```

Comment: DataOutputStream is just a wrapper, with helper functions. You can use whatever xOutputStream you want on both ends.

Comment: Yes, i know. But my strong feeling is that DataOutputStream is used on one side. That is why he is seeing the error.

Comment: Whilst this is not the cause of his problem (he's merely writing bytes to it, not multiple different formats), using `DataOutputStream` is indeed the wrong choice. It's intented to be used for creating `.dat` files.

Comment: @RameshPVK, I tried to change to https protocol because server also supports https.. but i got SSLException error.. PKI something.. i don't understand... how can i fix that error?